# Generating fixed length random numbers

Tags: python, random

Well, hello everybody. this is my very first piece of code i've ever written, but i am willing to learn. basically i want to generate random numbers/passwords. The script should ask at first some things (have not implemented all right now).

1. length = length of generated passwords (fixed value)
2. pmaximum = amount of generated passwords
3. chars = which chars should be used for generating (i want to short this one so i can choose between LC, UC and numbers) 
   Choosing between:

   string.letters[0:52] + string.digits + string.punctuation

this is my code right now, generating a valueerror;

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import string, random

#=============== Router Password Generator ==============

print 'Welcome to passwordlist generator'

length=input('length of generated passwords: ')
pmaximum=input('maximum amount of generated passwords: ')
chars=raw_input('which chars to use: ')

string=''

filename = raw_input('assign wordlist name: ')
f_extns = filename.split('.')

for count in xrange(0,pmaximum):
    for x in random.sample(chars,length):
        string+=x

file.write(string+'\n')

string=''

file.close()

print 'Done'


#================ RPG END ===============
```

i've wrote this using snippets from the web, i have a bit understanding of coding but i am here to learn, if someone could've explain some things i would be very happy so i can understand this code better if it works.

Comment: Please add concrete input and full error message (with trace and line numbers). Consider re-reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `for x in random.randrangec(chars,length):` There's no Python function called `randrangec()` as far as I am aware. Please explain what you want this to do - hint: even if it existed, you are very likely using it wrongly...

Comment: just typed it wrong.. my bad.. edited it.

Comment: Start with not shadowing the built-ins like `string` and `file` - use your own variable names that are not already part of Python.

Comment: means i rename file to data, as example?